# Keep log file for pushing data from python to Kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka

```
# importing the required libraries from time import sleep 
from json import dumps 
from kafka import KafkaProducer

# initializing the Kafka producer 
my_producer = KafkaProducer( bootstrap_servers = ['localhost:9092'], value_serializer = lambda x:dumps(x).encode('utf-8') )
# generating the numbers ranging from 1 to 500 
for n in range(10): 
    my_data = {'num' : n} 
    my_producer.send('testnum', value = my_data) 
    sleep(1) 
for n in range(10):
    if(n%2==0): 
        json_data= {'num' :n} 
         my_producer.send('testnum1',value = json_data) 
    sleep(1)
```

Could any one help me to set log for this file.

Comment: Please fix your formatting

Answer (score 0):

You've not printed anything, but if you want a log file, use python logging module, or simple shell redirection

```
python producer.py > out.log
```